# UI testing - No matches found for Descendants matching type... recording generated code

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

I am getting an error

`No matches found for Find: Descendants matching type NavigationBar from input {(
    Application, 0x60400019b790, pid: 20515, label: '<appname>'
)}`

but the code was generated by the recording function of XCUITest so I don't understand why it can't find the navbar. I have added an `accessibilityIdentifier` that is a localized string called `dashboardNavBar` to try and use that to find it instead but I am having trouble querying it. The current code I am using is:

```
func testLoginLogout() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    //login credentials and other code that takes me to dashboard of app
    app.navigationBars["Dashboard"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 2).tap()
    app.sheets["Do you want to Logout ?"].buttons["OK"].tap()
}
```

and the `app.navigationBars...` line is the line that throws the error above. I was hoping someone could tell me why it is unable to locate this navBar or whatever the problem is, and how I can fix it or work around it using the `accessibilityIdentifier`. Thanks.

Comment: The recorded code saying that the element you want to tap is a button. You can tap on that button directly like app.buttons["AccessibilityID"].tap().  Else you can find it by debugging mode and type po app.buttons.debugdescription | Then it will print all the buttons. Then you can also Access the element by app.buttons.element(boundBy : indexofSpecificelement).tap().  let me know your findings.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's might be a workaround and not a real solution, but what I did when I encountered this problem is added a check if the element exist and trying to run the same action two times. When you make a segue after this action, the element should not exist, and the second attempt to invoke won't be executed. For instance:

```
    func testLoginLogout() {
            let app = XCUIApplication()
            if (app.navigationBars["Dashboard"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 2).exists) {
                app.navigationBars["Dashboard"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 2).tap()
            }
// and if you will call it again the element should not exists, otherwise it will be called again

            if (app.navigationBars["Dashboard"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 2).exists) {
                app.navigationBars["Dashboard"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 2).tap()
            }

            if (app.sheets["Do you want to Logout ?"].buttons["OK"].exists) {
                app.sheets["Do you want to Logout ?"].buttons["OK"].tap()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue on my end with error in logs "***No matches found for Descendants matching type Button from input..***"

Got it resolved by implementing `isScreenLoaded()` function with a timeout as per below sample:

```
func isLoaded() {
    XCTAssertEqual(app?.staticTexts["Some screen text goes here.."].waitForExistence(timeout: 5), true)
  }
  func testMyScreen() {
    app = ApplicationManager.shared.launchApplication(launchEnvironment: ["screenName": "myScreen"])
    isLoaded()
    if let keyboard = app?.keyboards.firstMatch {
      verifyScreen(without: keyboard, identifier: "MyScreen",
             perPixelTolerance: 0.05,
             overallTolerance: 0.002)
    }
  }
```